# How to Rename xml elements and use the new names in the same XSL styleSheet?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xsl file for html output. the xsl handles an old format of xml whixh I want to renew now. Therefore I need to rename the old elements names to the new names I'm using the new names in the following xsl code. How can I do this?
I tried

```
<xsl:template match="OldName">
<NewName><xsl:value-of select="."/></NewName>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
some code... </xsl:template>
```

and then I tried to access

```
<xsl:value-of select="NewName"/>
```

but got nothing while when using the OldName I got the value

Comment: you can make use of variable to store the output (renamed xml). Then pass the variable value to other templates.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using XSLT2, you can use a [two-phase transformation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#d5e12785).

Comment: In XSLT 1, you can do multi-phase transformations like this if you have the `node-set()` extension function available. See http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:value-of select="NewName"/>` looks at the input, not the output. And in the input, there is no NewName. To make use of the NewName, you would have to parse it twice; once renewing the names, and once doing formatting.